# recurly - ajax howto

Tags: recurly

I just integrated recurly.js with my website.

```
  Recurly.buildSubscriptionForm({
        target : '#recurly_form',
        planCode:plan_code,
        successURL: 'payment_success',
        signature:sign_val
    });
```

now can I send request ajax way, so when payment succeeded, it will inform me some callback function

Answer (score 1):

sorry. I was too hurry to ask question. I found solution in recurly document.  Here is solution

```
Recurly.buildSubscriptionForm({
    target : '#recurly_form',
    planCode:plan_code,
    successHandler:function(token){
        alert("Payment Success");
    },
    signature:sign_val
});
```

instead of successUrl, use  successHandler.